# Запуск программы под .net framework младшей версии

Tags: c#, .net, совместимость

скомпилировал проект под .net framework 4.0
например
а на компьютере где будет использоваться
стоит например 3.5 версия

вопрос... прога запуститься или нет?

Comment: нет, не запустится, потребует именно ту версию на которой компилировали.

Answer (score 2):

Нет, не запустится, потребует именно ту версию на которой компилировали, или выше по минорной, при этом необходимо учитывать, что мажорная версия сюда не входит.

Comment: А на 4.5 запустится?

Comment: @АндрейNOP: Запустится

Comment: Я просто к тому, чтобы вы давали ответы чуть более подробные, которые смогут покрыть несколько возможных однотипных вопросов в будущем

Comment: Вот, например, проект скомпилирован под 3.5, но он не запустится на 4.0. А ваш ответ утверждает, что запустится

Comment: @АндрейNOP с чего вы взяли ? разве не действует правило, что последующие версии поддерживают предыдущие ?

Comment: @Lolidze, ну так, приходилось специально ставить 3.5, чтобы запускать некоторые приложения. MS вот даже мануалы предоставляет: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh506443(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @АндрейNOP оу, сколько лет работаю с c# ни разу не сталкивался с подобной ситуацией. Спасибо, полезно

Comment: @АндрейNOP SupportedRuntime в конфиге не помогло?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, а это во всех случаях поможет? Приложение не мое, а стороннее. Напишите свой ответ?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Должно помочь, вот статья: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-configure-an-app-to-support-net-framework-4-or-4-5 . Можно и к чужому приложению подложить конфиг. На отдельный ответ не тянет, т.к. вопрос все же про запуск именно на младшей версии. Пусть Yami дополнит свой ответ, если считает нужным.