# Запустится ли приложение?

Tags: c#, .net

Запустится ли приложение, если скомпилировано под .Net Framework 3.5,
на компьютере, где стоит .Net Framework 4.5, например?

Comment: да.............

Comment: @Embedder это не дубликат, там в другую сторону в вопросе.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин В ответе к вопросу-дублю,  _Андрей NOP_ приводит ссылку на MS-й документ. Небольшая выдержка из него:  `платформа .NET Framework 3.5 не устанавливается автоматически вместе с Windows 8, Windows 8.1 или Windows 10, и ее необходимо включить отдельно, чтобы зависящие от нее приложения работали` ну и далее по тексту. Так что, по факту, ответ там присутствует.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин а в Windows 7 какой версии .NET Framework автоматически устанавливается? Т.е. оригинальная чистая Windows 7 Pro например

Comment: @Embedder вы написали что возможен дубликат вопроса, это не дубликат вопроса.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин а в Windows 8, 8.1 и Windows 10 какая версия устанавливается автоматически?

Comment: @ara_ara не могу сказать точно

Comment: @ara_ara по версиям ОС: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2007/03/14/mailbag-what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-what-version-of-the-os/

Comment: @default locale я так понимаю, что это которые по умолчанию включены в образы .iso (оригинальных версий)

Comment: @Embedder а в WIndows 7 как? 3.0 или 3.5

Comment: @ara_ara Windows 7 (all editions) includes the .NET Framework 3.5.1 as an OS component

Answer (score 4):

> Платформа .NET Framework 4.5 и ее доработанные выпуски обратно
>   совместимы с приложениями, созданными с помощью более ранних версий
>   .NET Framework. Иными словами, приложения и компоненты, созданные с
>   использованием предыдущих версий платформы .NET Framework, будут без
>   внесения изменений работать в .NET Framework 4.5. Однако по умолчанию
>   приложения выполняются в той версии среды CLR, для которой они были
>   разработаны, поэтому, чтобы обеспечить возможность выполнения
>   приложения в .NET Framework 4.5, может потребоваться предоставить файл
>   конфигурации.

Читаем полный текст [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ff602939(v=vs.110).aspx) и [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/version-compatibility).

Comment: Хм, а я уже поверил [этому](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/777381/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-net-framework-%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8#comment1217005_777386)

Comment: @tym32167 на практике если ставишь программу для старых версий, то зачастую он запрашивает их установить, увы. И это согласутеся с текстом что привёл в цитате, что для работы на более новых версиях требуются специальные настройки, а если их в программе нет, то либо сам делай (но я про это раньше и не знал), либо ставь старую версию. Честно то мне проще старую версию поставить.

Comment: Я правильно понял - то есть как бы обратная совместимость есть, то это такой гемор, что можно сказать, что нет?

Comment: @tym32167 честно говоря я не эксперт в этом вопросе, но мой опыт говорит об этом. Но тут по сути два вопроса, обратная совместимость для программы где ты автор, тут можно настроить конфигурацию, как сказано в статье и это должно решить ситуацию, и пользователям уже не придётся ничего делать. А другая ситуация когда ты пользователь, пользователю это настраивать в конфиг файле думаю проблемно, проще установить старую версию. Да большинство пользователей про эти конфиги и не слышали никогда. Да и я сам про них никогда раньше не слышал, хотя сколько лет уже работаю с .NET

Comment: @tym32167 я думаю про полноценную обратную совместимость можно говорить на уровне кода, скажем я пишу на C# 7, появился C# 8 и мой код продолжает работать. А вот на уровне ASP технологий, уже сколько лет выходят новые версии которые по сути перечёркивают старые. Да новые несомненно лучше и они классные, но всё-же как-то грустно от того что мягкого перехода нету и надо полностью изучать фактически с нуля новую технологию.

Comment: @tym32167 конечно это уже offtopic но раз тема поднялась, хочу сказать, я для себя нашёл Vue.js движок, и теперь можно писать код по сути не изучая премудрости Razor, и я этому несказанно рад, так как эти новые версии постоянное переобучение, и совершенно не факт что в следующей новой версии не похерят то что было ранее.

Comment: @tym32167 я думаю что проблема в том, что технология не продумывается часто глубинно, со всеми деталями, для людей и с Любовью, а делается потому что модно, потому что есть у других, и потому что актуально, что бы было. А такие технологии зачастую попахивают... Ведь некачественная вещь обязательно в своё время проявит свою суть.

Comment: Ну среди версий c# тоже не везде есть обратная совместимость (на ум приходит тот же захват переменной внутри цикла), а про новые технологии - это да. Мало того, они ещё и меняются оч быстро - я вот в том году садился за .net core, прочитал книгу, прошел курсы, начал практиковаться, а часть API уже поменялась, вышли новые версии пакетов, даже тип файла проекта обратно сменили с Json на XML и все примеры без напильника не работают. Грусть печаль

Comment: Про vue.js - спасибо, погляжу. А то я после 3 попыток запилить angular в хобби проект, плюнул и забил :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72454/discussion-between---and-tym32167).

Comment: Чат заблочен фаерволом, только вечером, через 2-3 часа смогу заглянуть

Comment: @tym32167, специально сейчас выделил время и заморочился, проверил 2 приложения. Первое приложение при установке ничего не говорит и не предупреждает, устанавливается нормально независимо от наличия .NET 3.5, запуск при наличии версии 3.5 нормальный, при отсутствии приложение не запускается, вообще ничего не выводит, никаких сообщений об ошибках и прочего, после добавления строчки `<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />` в конфиг - ничего не изменилось, приложение так же не запускается и ничего не пишет.

Comment: Второе приложение отказалось ставиться при отсутствии .NET 3.5, наверное проверка зашита в код инсталятора. Установил 3.5, установил приложение. При запуске с установленным 3.5 всё штатно работает, при попытке запуска без 3.5 приложение не запускается, вылазит стандартное окно Windows с предложением установить .NET 3.5, после добавления в конфиг строчки `<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />` приложение нормально запускается и работает (функционал, конечно, не проверял). Так что в общем случае нельзя сказать, что есть обратная совместимость. Особенно это касается перехода 3.5-4.0

Comment: @АндрейNOP да, я примерно так и представлял. Спасибо